# Resetting visuals for checked rows in a table via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After clicking on the reset button, my checkbox does not work anymore.

My main issue is regarding the .click(function())

```
$('.button').click(function(){


    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",false);
    $( "td" ).css( "background", "white");
    $( "td" ).css( "color", "#000000" );


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxxex32n/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re overriding the `style` attribute in such a way that the CSS rules are more specific than the style sheet.

Just replace

```
$( "td" ).css( "background", "white");
$( "td" ).css( "color", "#000000" );
```

by

```
$(".checked").removeClass("checked");
```

Comment: thank you xufox, was trying that out earlier on but i may have other conflicting codes earlier on. How do i rep you?